# LDAP object class violation: attribute ou not allowed in suffix?

Tags: ldap, openldap

I am about to set up a LDAP directory. It is used as a tool to communicate user permissions from a web application to WebDav file system access, e.g. adding a user to the web platform shall allow login to the file system with the same credentials. There are no other usages intended. Following [this German tutorial](http://www.linupedia.org/opensuse/OpenLDAP) which encourages the use of the attributes `c`, `o`, `ou` etc. over `dc`, I configured the following suffix and root:

```
suffix                "ou=webtool,o=myOrg,c=de"
rootdn                "cn=ldapadmin,ou=webtool,o=myOrg,c=de"
```

Server starts and I can connect to it by [LDAP Admin](http://www.ldapadmin.org/), which reports “LDAP error: Object lacks”. Well, there aren’t any objects yet.

I now want to create the root and admin elements from shell. I created an `init.ldif` file:

```
dn: ou=webtool,o=myOrg,c=de
objectclass: dcObject
objectclass: organization
dc: webtool
o: webtool

dn: cn=ldapadmin,ou=webtool,o=myOrg,c=de
objectclass: organizationalRole
cn: ldapadmin
```

Trying to load the file runs into an error, telling me that `ou` is not allowed:

```
server:~ # ldapadd -x -D "cn=ldapadmin,ou=webtool,o=myOrg,c=de" -W -f init.ldif
Enter LDAP Password:
adding new entry "ou=webtool,o=myOrg,c=de"
ldap_add: Object class violation (65)
        additional info: attribute 'ou' not allowed
```

I am not using `ou` anywhere except in the suffix, so the question: Isn’t it allowed here? What *is* allowed here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numberous dependencies for the creation of elements, and error messages are rather confusing if you don’t know of the concept. The `objectclass` isn’t necessarily `dcObject` for the databases’ root node, as it is likely to guess when you read several tutoriales. Instead, it must correspond to the object’s type: Here, for a name starting with `ou=`, it must be `organizationalUnit`. I found this piece of information in [these tables](http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ape/). Further on, the object class dictates which properties must and can be added in the record. Here, `organizationalUnit` must have an `ou:` entry and must not have neither `dc:` nor `o:` entries. Thus, the healthy `init.ldif` file looks like that:

```
dn: ou=webtool,o=myOrg,c=de
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: LDAP server for my webtool

dn: cn=ldapadmin,ou=webtool,o=myOrg,c=de
objectclass: organizationalRole
cn: ldapadmin
```

Note: The page also states: “While many objectClasses show no MUST attributes you must (ouch) follow any hierarchy […] to determine if this is the really case.” I thought that would mean my root record would have to provide the must fields for `c=` and `o=` (`c:` and `o:`, respectively) but this is **not** the case.